# GUI редактор для MySQL

Tags: linux, sql, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста бесплатный GUI редактор для mysql, чтобы можно было связи между таблицами устанавливать и т.п.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поищите в репозиториях Вашего дистрибутива [mysql-workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). Очень функциональный и удобный.

Answer (score 5):

[MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько хороших вариантов: [TOra](http://torasql.com/about), [Emma](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/emma-graphical-toolkit-for-mysql-database-developers-and-administrators.html) (оба есть в стандартном репозитории)

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать Вам попробовать dbForge Studio for MySQL, есть и русская редакция и бесплатный экспресс эдишен.